# Using window.print() in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to print the content of a function in react but getting 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null`

function:

```
export default function Home(props) {
    return (
       <h4>Some other contents</h4>
       <button className='btn' type='button' onClick={printDiv('printMe')}>Print</button>
   )
}

function Data(props) {
   return (
   <div id='printMe'>
      <p>Some contents in here returning from my database</p>
      <p>On an html table</p>
   </div>
  )
}

function printDiv(divName) {
  let printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  let originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

  window.print();

  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

So far, once the application is loaded I get the error. I'm not sure what's causing the issues.

Comment: The value of `onClick` has to be a function; what happens if you pass a function? Like `onClick={() => printDiv('printMe')}`.

Comment: This works. Really helpful, thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I assume this script is located inside your `<head>` tag. Are you running your code after the page loads?

If you want to access the DOM, you need to make sure that the DOM element(s) you're trying to access actually exist.

Try doing this on the script tag:

```
<script src="path/to/your/script.js" defer></script>
```

The `defer` attribute makes it run after the page finishes loading; hence, it'll have proper access to the DOM.